# Select Statement with multiple true conditions Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to make a macro run with a state case with multiple conditions, i know that we are supost to use a " , " to separate multiple conditions, but what can we use to separate conditions that both have to be met?

here is the code

```
Select Case Cells(i, 248)
        Case "B":    Fees_Jan = (Cells(i, 267).Value - Cells(i, 265)) / 2
        Case "C":    Fees_Jan = (Cells(i, 267).Value - Cells(i, 265)) * 0.25
        Case "A", Cells(i, 250) = "BANANAS", Cells(i, 236) = "MAÇAS": Fees_Jan = (Cells(i, 267).Value * 0.35 / 1 / 2)
        Case "A", Cells(i, 250) = "PERAS", Cells(i, 236) = "MORANGOS": Fees_Jan = ((Cells(i, 262).Value) * 0.2 / 2) + (Cells(i, 263).Value - (Cells(i, 265).Value) / 3)
        Case Else:     Fees_Jan = Cells(i, 265).Value / 2
    End Select
```

if i isolate and run only the last Case "A", it works fine, but wen i run all the code it doesent work well.. can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could evaluate the Select for True.

```
Select Case True
    Case Cells(i, 248) = "B"
        Fees_Jan = (Cells(i, 267).Value - Cells(i, 265)) / 2
    Case Cells(i, 248) = "C"
        Fees_Jan = (Cells(i, 267).Value - Cells(i, 265)) * 0.25
    Case Cells(i, 248) = "A" And Cells(i, 250) = "BANANAS" And Cells(i, 236) = "WILLHILL_CLEVERADV_HYBRID"
        Fees_Jan = (Cells(i, 267).Value * 0.35 / 1 / 2)
    Case Cells(i, 248) = "A" And Cells(i, 250) = "PERAS" And Cells(i, 236) = "MORANGOS"
        Fees_Jan = ((Cells(i, 262).Value) * 0.2 / 2) + (Cells(i, 263).Value - (Cells(i, 265).Value) / 3)
    Case Else
        Fees_Jan = Cells(i, 265).Value / 2
End Select
```

Comment: it gives me a runtime error 13 type mismatch (i only run the last case "A", the other code was commented out

Comment: Did you catch my recent edit? I missed changing to `Select Case True`

Comment: let me try this